# Android custom camera view larger than screen

Tags: java, android, mobile, camera

I am trying to build a custom camera view which fills the whole screen by stretching the preview while maintaining the aspect ratio and having the parts outside the screen cropped. I have been unable to get the surface view which the camera uses to stretch larger than the screen size. I can get it to be smaller than the screen, or have it stretched to match the screen exactly which ruins the aspect ratio. How do I go about getting the camera to fill the screen without losing the aspect ratio?

Comment: hi, did you managed to solve this? thanks a lot